# Reduce float precission to save memory in Python

Tags: python, memory, precision

I am preparing a code to create an array of 10^5 rows and 10^4 columns with Python. Each element of the array is a float (1.504096744947185, *e.g.*), which takes 24 Bytes, so the whole array would need 24 GB. However, I only need a precision of 6 decimal places instead of the default 15 decimal places given by Python. I have tried the `round` function, but it doesn't really save memory.

Would it be possible to reduce the precision of the numbers to save memory?

Comment: Are you using NumPy, and if so, are you familiar with dtypes?

Comment: Python only provides a single size of float object.  You can get more compact storage using the built-in `array` module - but I'd suggest you try the `numpy` 3rd-party module instead - it directly supports multidimensional arrays, and can do bulk math operations on your arrays far faster than any loop you could write in plain Python.

Comment: All said and in addition, you can convert your floats to `numpy.int16` (2 bytes)